# SARIMAX model in R

Tags: r

I would fit a `SARIMAX` model with temperature as exogenous variable in `R`. Can I do that with `xreg` function present in the `package TSA`? 
I thought to fit the model as:

`fit1 = arima(x, order=c(p,d,q), seasonal=list(order=c(P,D,Q), period=S), xreg=temp)`

is that correct or I have to use other function of `R`?
if it itsn't correct: which steps should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the *forecast* package, it's great:

```
# some random data
obs <- ts(rnorm(120,0,3) + 1:120 + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:120)/12), frequency=12)
exogenous_data <- rnorm(length(obs), 20, 30)

require(forecast)
# build the model (check ?auto.arima)
model <- auto.arima(obs, xreg = exogenous_data)

# forecasting
forec <- forecast(model, xreg = rnorm(10, 20, 30))

# quick way to visualize things
plot(forec)

# model diagnosis
tsdiag(model)

# model info
summary(forec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Fernando. I would know if it's possibile to fit an exogenous variable in `R` with `xreg`, my "x" data is price and i would fit it with temperature. is it possible with this method?

Answer (score 1):

I won't suggest you to use auto.arima(). Depending on the model you want to fit it may return poor results, as for example when working with some complex SARIMA models the difference between the models done manually and with auto.arima() were noticeable, auto.arima() do not even returned white noise innovations (as it is expected), while manual fits, of course, did.